# columns unknown when applying function to dataframe in r

Tags: r, function, dplyr

To simplify, say, I have a dataset like this:

```
num = c(1,2,3,"NA",3,4,1,2,1)
char = c('a','b','s','s','s','s','a','s','s')
t = as.data.frame(cbind(num,char))
```

and I wrote a function to find top 5 values of each column:

```
 func_top5 = function(x){t%>%
    filter(!is.na(x))%>%
    group_by(x)%>%
    summarise(number_of_same_value = n())%>%
    arrange(desc(number_of_same_value))%>%
    slice(1:5)}
```

when I tried to apply this function to the df,

```
apply(t,2,func_top5)
```

it returned the error:

Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `x` is unknown

But when I just use the function separately, it works totally fine:

```
t%>%
  filter(!is.na(num))%>%
  group_by(num)%>%
  summarise(number_of_same_value = n())%>%
  arrange(desc(number_of_same_value))%>%
  slice(1:5)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
     num number_of_same_value
  <fctr>                <int>
1      1                    3
2      2                    2
3      3                    2
4      4                    1
5     NA                    1
```

I think the problem might be the "group_by" function.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the quosure way to solve this.  Assuming that they input argument 'x' is not quoted, we can convert it to quosure with `enquo`, then evaluate within the `group_by`, `filter` using bang-bang operator(`!!`).  Note that, it is better to have the dataset object also as the input argument for useability of the function in a more general way.  It is not clear whether the missing values are quoted or not.  The more acceptable way if it is a true NA is `is.na`

```
func_top5 <- function(df, x){
   x <- enquo(x)
   df %>%
       filter(! (!!(x) %in% c("NA", "")))%>%
        group_by(!! x)%>%
        summarise(number_of_same_value = n())%>%
        arrange(desc(number_of_same_value))%>%
        slice(1:5)
     }
```

We call it by

```
func_top5(df1, col1)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   col1  number_of_same_value
#   <chr>                <int>
#1 b                        3
#2 a                        2
```

---

One option to do this on multiple columns would be

```
map(names(t), ~ func_top5(t1, !! rlang::sym(.x)))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#    num number_of_same_value
#  <dbl>                <int>
#1  1.00                    3
#2  2.00                    2
#3  3.00                    2
#4  4.00                    1
#5 NA                       1

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  char  number_of_same_value
#  <chr>                <int>
#1 s                        6
#2 a                        2
#3 b                        1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b", "NA", "", "a", "b", "b"), 
      col2 = rnorm(7), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I was trying to use "apply()" function to apply this function to each column of the dataframe, so if I add df into the function, I am not sure how to apply that.
I tried to use enquo() and bangbang operator, but it returned the error:   the argument has already been evaluated.

Comment: @XiwenChen  Based on the code you showed, it was not clear

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. But do you have any advice about how to apply this function to columns of a dataset? x stands for each column. Thank you.

Comment: @XiwenChen  Could you please update your post with a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Yes. I updated my question. Could you please check whether there is a solution for that? Thank you.

Comment: @XiwenChen  In your examples, you created `NA` as quoted.  It will not be a string and not an NA.  Just use `NA` instead of `"NA"`.  Secondly, data.frame(num, char) is better than `as.data.frame(cbind` as the latter changes to matrix and matrix can have a single type

Comment: @XiwenChen  Try with `num = c(1,2,3,NA,3,4,1,2,1);
char = c('a','b','s','s','s','s','a','s','s');
t1 <- data.frame(num, char, stringsAsFactors = FALSE); func_top5(t1, num)`

Comment: @XiwenChen  Updated my solution

Comment: I tried, but the same problem came up. I think the problem is "group_by" function because when I just do "filter", everything works perfectly fine. When I add group_by, it will have the error.

Comment: @XiwenChen  I am using the same data 't' in your post. What is the dplyr version?  I am using `dplyr_0.7.4`